# Leaves unnecessary Blank Space between elements in class row

Tags: html, css

Actually I don't know how to describe the issue. I have designed a model, in which I have specify some elements in class `row`. But after 3 elements it leaves unnecessary spaces. Is there any issue with bootstrap class `row`?.[Checkout the link. Click on register](http://revolutionindia.org.in/)

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-4 standard">
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4 school_name">
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4 occupation">
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-4 father_income">
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4 blood_group">
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4 type_of_wastage">
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-4 photo">
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4 edit_photo" style="display: none;">
    <div class="form-group">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4 city">
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4 address">
    <div class="form-group">
    </div>
  </div>


</div>
```

Comment: Please, can you add some screenshot or more detailed of what your problem is? I can't figure out what's the problem

Answer (score 1):

The Bootstrap grid syntax is wrong. A row in Bootstrap contains 12 columns. If you have already 12 columns in a row, you must open a new row. In your case, you must open a new row after you used the `col-sm-4` class 3 times. So it must look like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have 9 elements and on id basis i hide some of elements. so if i write code like this and hide two elements from first row. Then it shows first element then leaves spaces. Then second row continues  from new line. All elements should be continues. Even if i hide any number of elements thats why i did like this

Answer (score 0):

set some min-height to all columns in register

```
.modal-body .col-sm-4 {
    min-height: 86px;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can't put all these columns in one row. with col-sm-4, you can have only 3 columns per row. after that, you need to create another row. Because in bootstrap grid system there are 12 columns per row. If you need all hose in one row, you have to use col-sm-1. But I don't think it would be a good idea. Better thing is, since you have 10 elements here, either use col-sm-4 in 4 rows or col-sm-3 in 3 rows.

Answer (score -1):

You have write wrong syntax.One row in Bootstrap contains 12 blocks only. That's why unnecessary space is being shown.